# Buying a SIM card to use on extensive travel elsewhere in the EU

Tags: cellphones

I currently live in Germany but I am 2-3 months in Spain a year. I only a a bad DSL connection but the mobile network here is quite good. However, they charge a lot for only little data. As all roaming fees were abolished by the European Union this year, I was thinking about buying a SIM card in Denmark or another country where the data plans are incredible cheap and then use the card in Spain (has to be Vodafone). Does anyone know which card would be the best to do this and how to get one?

Comment: Note that the free roaming access is meant to be only used for travel related reasons, therefore the law allow providers to limit your data if they find you're not really using their plain locally. Most providers I found already have it in their T&Cs how they limit access if they find you're using their product mostly from abroad

Comment: @SztupY I am curious to see how it works in practice, for someone travelling for a couple of months, it may not matter. You could even get a new SIM card the next year.

Comment: @Relaxed thats the plan

Comment: Most providers I saw have a 2-3 month window, where if you use your phone abroad more than locally, the next month they will start charging you for usage, so you probably need a new sim every 3 months

Comment: Whatever is "best" will fluctuate a lot when any of the 30 countries that participate in free EU roaming change their prices and T&Cs. Therefore this is a very wide price shopping question.